# Open csv file improper encoding

Tags: php, csv

When I open the csv file

```
$str = file_get_contents($filename);      
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str,"utf-8","sjis"); 
var_dump($str);
```

It shows like this

```
\0000\000.\0000\0000\0008\0000\0005\0007\000,\0000\000.\0000\0001\0000 ....
```

At first I think , this is the problem of encoding, so I added  `mb_convert_encoding` but in vain.

What cause this improper encoding?

Comment: you can not read csv file using file_get_contents();

Comment: What does the file look like as it is ? It really depends on what software produced the csv file. Encoding problems in csv content are highly common.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi ... of course you can, it's just a text file - won't be parsed into an array or anything but it can be read in fine (permissions permitting).

Comment: Do you know what the CSV's original encoding is? As a general rule, UTF-8 all the things!

Answer (score 1):

Better you can do like this:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Code copied from :http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php
alternatively : http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php